# Exclude files based on name when calling from_catalog

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am reading data via

```
glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "ta")
```

from parquet files on a s3 bucket.
Unfortunately, it seems the bucket contains a non-parquet file (`last_ingest_partition`) which causes the following error:
`An error occurred while calling o92.getDataFrame. s3://cdh/measurements/ta/last_ingest_partition is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [49, 45, 49, 50]`

Is there a possibility to exclude this file from being read?
I have tried somethig like

```
glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "ta", additional_options={"exclusions" : "[\"**last_ingest_partition\""})
```

but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have found out and what solved my problem:

1. When I switch my code to `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` instead of `create_data_frame.from_catalog` and added a `.toDF()` afterwards, everything worked fine for me.
2. For `create_dynamic_frame` I could also use exlusions as additional options: `.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "testdb1", table_name = "cxexclude",additional_options={"exclusions": "[\"**{json,parquet}**\"]"})`
3. For `create_data_frame class`, there are limitations: Spark DataFrame partition filtering doesn't work.